# AMP missing embedded video

Tags: amp-html

I got an AMP issue for a website I manage. I received the message type [WNC-10036043] on webmasters tools.

It says "`Google systems have detected AMP pages on your site that are missing videos contained in their corresponding canonical pages.`" as you can see in the first picture here below

[image]

I tested any page of the site with AMP VALIDATOR tool, and everything was AMP compliant. No errors.

[**EDIT**]
Here the response of the Google's AMP validator
[image]
[**/EDIT**]

Moreover, checking in webmasters tools: "`Search Appearance -> Accelerated Mobile Pages`", I got the highlight, in the screenshot here below. Then I went to investigate

[image]

where I saw many pages (almost all) are reported with the same issue. In the second screenshot, you see the details

[image]

this because all the pages are using one template.
I checked the code but it seems ok (please here below)

This the URL tested: https://www.liciafox.net/amp/songs/fragile

here below the screenshot of the code, that shows that the JS library is loaded

[image]

and here below the second part of the HTML AMP code implemented

[image]

here the canonical page

[image]

I'm wondering what should I do in order to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

the issue is into the first part of the URL.
Posting a video form youtube, on canonical page I did use the format

```
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/watch?v={videocode}
```

the AMP code, instead, doesn't let anybody to decide whether use `-nocookie` option or not.

The AMP tag is indeed:

```
<amp-youtube 
             data-videoid="{videocode}"
             layout="responsive"
             width="480"
             height="270">
</amp-youtube>
```

which calls this address format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videocode}
```

rather than this one:

```
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/watch?v={videocode}
```

At the current state of the things, there is not way to make AMP call with the `-nocookie´option, see the doc [amp-youtube tag](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-youtube) and in the [AMP Examples](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-youtube/)

The AMP analyzer, on `Webmasters Tools > Search appearance > Accelerated Mobile Pages`, detects the Content mismatch, and it consider this: `Missing embedded video (Non-critical issue)`.

Rewriting the YouTUBE link on the canonical page, in the format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videocode}
```

The issue is solved

Answer (score -1):

looking at your canonical page, it's referring in a wrong way to the AMP one, in fact it is:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="//www.liciafox.net/amp/songs/fragile">
```

Try to remove // in front of the URL

Comment: do you think that the automatic discovery of the protocol can generate this issue? Interesting. I followed your suggestion and I asked to Google to rescan the page, however it will be necessary a lot, to see if ti's solved.
With AMP validator everything was and is ok :-/

Comment: Google has new results: it didn't worked. Thus this was not the supposed solution

Comment: UPDATE: the removal of the `//` lead to the following issue, creating a huge amount of errors (from Google Webmasters Tools):

**AMP URL:**  `https://www.liciafox.net/songs/www.liciafox.net/amp/songs/fragile `

while before ti was working fine (automatic discovery of the protocol)